# Removing prefix from response body on form submission in js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I have created a form using Angular where in post submission the response body is coming with a prefix of datatype in this format:

```
{
 field1: 'String: input1',
 field2: 'String: input2',
 field3: 'Number: input3'
}
```

Is there an easier way to get this in following format

```
{
 field1: 'input1',
 field2: 'input2',
 field3: 'input3'
}
```

Currently I am going recursive over this to remove general prefix like Number & String

Please note the form type used here is Select-Options

Comment: hi, you can easily remove using regular for in loop `for(prop in obj){
 obj[prop] = obj[prop].substr(obj[prop].indexOf(" ")+1);
}` this is if obj is your returned object

Comment: Is there an easier way to remove it during form submission. For instance when I submit form using Input filed there is not data-type prefix inclusion, while when I submit form using Select-Options there is data type prefix inclusion

Comment: I'm not sure I'm really clear on the question here.  Are you suggesting that Angular is submitting the elements to your server looking like this, or that you are receiving data from your server in this format?

Comment: and what is `Select-Options`?  it almost sounds like you are trying to submit a form with multiple select boxes?

Comment: better yet, could you submit your HTML code for the form, including the ngOptions

Comment: You can use:

var arr = obj.split(':');
So, 
arr[0] <= type
arr[1].trim() <= value

Comment: @Claies: Yes. My angular application is submitting the form in that format. I am using ngOptions currently. Here is the code:
`<select id="make" ng-model="ngMake" ng-change="getModelData(ngMake)" ng-options="ngMake as ngMake for ngMake in  make"></select>`

Comment: I would recommend that you update your question with the additional code you posted in the comments, as well as a basic example of what `make` and `ngMake` are.  also, I don't recommend prefixing any variable names with `ng`, unless you expect people to wonder if they are framework variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1rst. I would recommend that you do not name your model "ngMake", it is a bad practice. "ng" is a reserved prefix for angularjs.  let's call it "makeObj". it will be bound to the model when you iterate over the "make" array.

2nd, your use of ng-options is wrong. In your case, it should be used like this: `select as label for value in array`   or `label for value in array`
where
 - select should be "makeObj.id" ( the object property you wish to send)
 - label should be the data you wish to display as an option, "makeObj.name"
 - value should be "makeObj"
 - array is "make"

so basically :

```
<select 
  id="makeObj" 
  ng-model="makeObj" 
  ng-change="getModelData(makeObj)" 
  ng-options="makeObj.id as makeObj.name for makeObj in make">
</select>
```

and if you do not wish to get a property but the whole JSON object:

```
<select 
  id="makeObj" 
  ng-model="makeObj" 
  ng-change="getModelData(makeObj)" 
  ng-options="makeObjVal for makeObj in make">
</select>
```

This should fix your problem, there's no need for a function to get a substring.
you can learn more about ngOptions [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Comment: Thanks jfab. I am new to Ng-Options and I totally used the wrong syntax